# Spring integration durable pub sub channel

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Is it possible to configure durable pub sub channel in spring integration 2.1?

Answer (score 0):

Not without addition software like a

- AMQP broker (e.g. RabbitMQ) or
- JMS broker (e.g. ActiveMQ, HornetQ, etc) or
- Datagrid (e.g Gemfire)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can persist messages in any MessageStore implementation (JDBC, Mongo, Redis, GemFire) as well as backing the channel with JMS or AMQP.